# PHP removing all array items

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can anyone please help me to understand and fix; why the following code is clearing all the items from the array.
Code is meant to remove all items recursively in the array that do not have '_label' in their key

```
function checkiflabel($item,$key){
   if(strpos($key,'_label')!==false)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
function walk_recursive_remove (array $array, callable $callback) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            if (($callback($v, $k))==false)
                unset($array[$k]);
            else
                $array[$k] = walk_recursive_remove($v, $callback);
        } else {
            if (($callback($v, $k))==false) {
                unset($array[$k]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

I am calling this using

```
$data = walk_recursive_remove($data1,'checkiflabel');
print_r($data); die;
```

Its shows empty array and for sure $data1 is an array and has values because if I change

```
if (($callback($v, $k))==false)
```

to

```
if ($callback($v, $k))
```

it does remove all items that have _label and the rest items are fine.
Below is the print_r for $data1 with some data obfuscation

```
Array ( [1] => Array (
    [gridReviewerDecision] => ACCEPTED
    [gridReviewerDecision_label] => Accepted
    [gridReviewerComment] => ok
    [gridReviewerComment_label] => ok
    [gridReviewerAcceptedAmount] => 100
    [gridReviewerAcceptedAmount_label] => 100
    [gridUploadFilesByReviewer] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [appDocUid] => 5810427715e892c81ab34c8030653093
            [name] => drawing.pdf
            [version] => 1
            )
        )
    [gridUploadFilesByReviewer_label] => Array (
        [0] => drawing.pdf
        )
    [gridContest] => 1
    [gridContest_label] => true
    [gridTypeOfMOtive] => AAAAA
    [gridTypeOfMOtive_label] => BBBBB
    [gridComment] => test 1
    [gridComment_label] => test 1
    [gridUploadFiles] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [appDocUid] => 3735522335e892c08eefa43074490443
            [name] => drawing.jpg
            [version] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array (
            [appDocUid] => 6071415935e892c10331426048606075
            [name] => drawing.png
            [version] => 1
            )
        )
    [gridUploadFiles_label] => Array (
        [0] => drawing.jpg
        [1] => drawing.png
        )
    [gridContestationAmount] => 100
    [gridContestationAmount_label] => 100
    [DA_PLATFORME] => XXXXXX
    [DA_PLATFORME_label] => XXXXXX
    [EAN] => 3257980158208
    [EAN_label] => 3257980158208
    [DESIGNATIONARTICLE] => ZZZZZZ
    [DESIGNATIONARTICLE_label] => ZZZZZZ
    [VA] => 00
    [VA_label] => 00
    [DPROMORPERM] => P
    [DPROMORPERM_label] => P
    [CODERUPTURECOMMANDE] => 06
    [CODERUPTURECOMMANDE_label] => 06
    [DATELIVR] => 04/12/09
    [DATELIVR_label] => 04/12/09
    [NOCDE] => 12336422
    [NOCDE_label] => 12336422
    [RELIQUAT] => 
    )
  )
```

Comment: Hello. Please edit your question and outline what the code is *meant* to do

Comment: Thank You! edited it, hope it explains better!

Comment: Thank you again for the edit, I edited it again to provide a better example and have beautified the array as you did.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** My misunderstanding - you are working with associative arrays. This was not initially clear to me.

When I test your posted code against the following array:

```
$a = [
    'test' => 'a',
    'test2' => 'b',
    'test3' => 'c',
    'test_label' => 'd',
    'test_label_2' => [
        'test_label_3' => 'e',
        'test4' => [
            'test_label_4' => 'f'
        ]
    ]
];
```

It seems to do what you expect.

```
OUTPUT:
Array (
     [test_label] => d
     [test_label_2] => Array (
          [test_label_3] => e
     )
)
```

---

**Original Answer**

The issue is with the order of parameters.

```php
    if (($callback($v, $k))==false) {
        unset($array[$k]);
    }
```

In this case, `$v` is the string, and `$k` is the array index. So, your `checkiflabel` method is comparing the numeric array indexes to a string.

The solution is simply to reverse the order that you call the method with.

```
    if (($callback($k, $v))==false) {
        unset($array[$k]);
    }
```

As a small tip, in the future when you run into similar issues: You would've quickly noticed this by simply adding a `var_dump` to the `checkiflabel` method to ensure that the parameters are as you expected them to be! :)

Comment: Thank you very much and very kind of you for a quick reply, would you be kind to please recheck the same, I have added print_r dump pf my array in my original question.

Comment: @user13229327 seems I misunderstood your original question. See my edit. Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Thank you! your understanding is correct, I have put an exact dump of the array with _label keys, for me, the same code is giving an empty array, and it doesn't make sense to me don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: @user13229327 What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP version is 7.1.33

Comment: Testing your original code (top of your post) against the array in my reply, on PHP 7.1, produces the same array that I show in my answer. If you're not getting that result, then either my array does not represent the type of data you're processing (let me know if that's the case), or you're doing something else to the array that you're not showing. @user13229327